# How does event queue is processed in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, event-loop, libuv

I am learning through the architecture of Node.js. I have following questions.

1) Is event loop a part of libuv or v8?

2) If event loop is responsible for delegating the blocking call to libuv and putting the callback to the event queue, than how does the callback present in event queue goes to call stack for execution?

3) How v8 and libuv interact with each other in Node.js?

Diagram showing the Node Js architecture.

**Can anybody explain me how does v8 gets back the data from event queue to process it in the given diagram?

[image]

[Event Loop Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVst5.jpg)

Now can someone tell me which diagram shows the correct position of event loop in Node js architecture?

Comment: have a look at http://latentflip.com/loupe it is the best visualisation of how js is working

Comment: "*how does the callback present in event queue goes to call stack for execution*" - it gets popped from the event queue as soon as the current event has finished processing.

Comment: Seems like the diagram answers your questions nicely.

Comment: …or rather, the article where you found the diagram.

Comment: I have already seen his video but in his video he says that event loop is responsible for the interaction between the call stack and callback queue(event queue)… but then how event queue gets callback from libuv library?

Comment: @ScottMarcus The diagram shows that event loop is the part of libuv but then how does async operation callbacks are triggered, I mean that how does v8 gets what is in event queue.

Comment: Libuv’s role in NodeJS architecture is to abstract internal I/O complexities and provide a generalized interface to upper layers of Node, so that Node can perform platform independent asynchronous I/O without worrying about what platform it is run on.

Comment: @Shubh Yup but the question remains the same, does the v8 interact with libuv(event queue present inside libuv in the diagram)

Comment: The event queue has one job, keep a list of functions to be called in a certain order. When the JavaScript call stack is idle, the function that is first "in line" is passed to the call stack and called.

Comment: @ScottMarcus But according to this person https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1235&v=8aGhZQkoFbQ, that is the responsibility of event loop

Comment: Well eventqueue is different ,libuv is different . libuv is the c++ side of node js .V8 Just provides the interface such that things in c++ world can understand the js world something like a translator .Event queue is where the  callback waits to be executed in the call stack.

Comment: @Shubh than what is the event queue shown in the above diagram above called as it is shown as the part of libuv.

Comment: I guess this diagram lacks the clear insight. I will try writing a basic understandable answer, if someone here doesn't. See from the docs -http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/_images/architecture.png

Comment: @Shubh Ok, I am now convinced that event queue is not the part of libuv. But there should be some mechanism behind how callback in event queue gets poped out and pushed to call stack for execution.

Some tutorials or blogs have called that mechanism as event loop while some argue that event loop is a part of libuv, infact libuv official site says event loop is part of libuv and that event loop interact with libuv and event queue.

Comment: Well technically it is and there are 4 queues ,immediate queues ,closed handlers queues,io queues ,timers intervals queue .Eventqueue is nothing but a datastructure. You are confusing with javascript and node js .

Comment: @Shubh I have edited the question and added 1 more image above, can you help me by telling which one is correct position of event loop?

Answer (score 0):

1. Eventloop will be part of LIBUV
2. process.nextTick() taken care by LIBUV. Eventloop internally uses timers, I/O callbacks, idle or process, poll (incoming requests), check, close I/O callback, and connect to timers.
3. V8 engine takes care of connecting jscode or application to nodejs API.